# What are the values of effective mass approximation

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics

For my research work i am trying to calculate band gap of zinc oxide theoratically and found this [paper (Determination of the Particle Size Distribution of Quantum Nanocrystals from Absorbance Spectr)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/adma.200304904). What i am doing is I am making a small matlab programm which will reporduce the results using the same values from the above paper. I used the values given in the paper to make the program

[image]

**Absorbtion onset**

$\lambda ^{onset}=\frac{c*h}{E^{*}}$

```
   Values used for calculating Band gap
8.85418782 ×  10^-12          permittivity of free space
1.60217657 ×  10^-19          charge of an electron
9.11 ×  10^-31                free electron mass
1.05457173 × 10^-34               hcut
0.59                      effective mass of holes
0.26                     effective mass of electrons
8.5                      relative permittivity
3.2                     zno bandgap
c                       velocity of light
```

But after running the programm i got these results

```
Size    Absorbtion Onset
1   6.21E-26
1.5 6.21E-26
2   6.21E-26
2.5 6.21E-26
3   6.21E-26
3.5 6.21E-26
4   6.21E-26
4.5 6.21E-26
5   6.21E-26
5.5 6.21E-26
6   6.21E-26
6.5 6.21E-26
7   6.21E-26
7.5 6.21E-26
8   6.21E-26
8.5 6.21E-26
9   6.21E-26
9.5 6.21E-26
10  6.21E-26
```

The results i got doesnt match with tha paper and I belive that my coding in matlab is correct but i am doubtful about the values i have taken for calculating band gap.

Can you help me with this

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.